# Regex to insert space with certain characters but avoid date and time

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I made a regex which inserts a space where ever there is any of the characters 
`-:\*_/;,` present for example `JET*AIRWAYS\INDIA/858701/IDBI  05/05/05;05:05:05 a/c` should be`JET* AIRWAYS\ INDIA/ 858701/ IDBI  05/05/05; 05:05:05 a/c`

The regex I used is `(?!a\/c|w\/d|m\/s|s\/w|m\/o)(\D-|\D:|\D\*|\D_|\D\\|\D\/|\D\;)`

I have added some words exceptions like a/c w/d etc. \D conditions given to avoid date/time values getting separated, but this created an issue, the numbers followed by the above mentioned characters never get split.

My requirement is 
 1. Insert a space after characters `-:\*_/;,`
 2. but date and time should not get split which may have `/ :` 
 3. need exception on words like a/c w/d

The following is the full code

```
Private Function formatColon(oldString As String) As String

      Dim reg As New RegExp: reg.Global = True: reg.Pattern = "(?!a\/c|w\/d|m\/s|s\/w|m\/o)(\D-|\D:|\D\*|\D_|\D\\|\D\/|\D\;)"     '"(\D:|\D/|\D-|^w/d)"
      Dim newString As String: newString = reg.Replace(oldString, "$1 ")
      formatColon = XtraspaceKill(newString)

    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use 3 replacements.

1. Replace all date and time special characters with a special macro that should never be found in your text, *e.g.* for `05/15/2018 4:06 PM`, something based on your name:

   ```
   05MANUMOHANSLASH15MANUMOHANSLASH2018 4MANUMOHANCOLON06 PM
   ```

   You can encode exceptions too, like this:

   ```
   aMANUMOHANSLASHc
   ```
2. Now run your original regex to replace all special characters.
3. Finally, unreplace the macros `MANUMOHANSLASH` and `MANUMOHANCOLON`.

---

Meanwhile, let me tell you why this is complicated in a single regex.

If trying to do this in a single regex, you have to ask, for each `/` or `:`, *"Am I a part of a date or time?"*

To answer that, you need to use `lookahead` and `lookbehind` assertions, the latter of which Microsoft has finally added support for.

But given a `/`, you don't know if you're between the first and second, or second and third parts of the date. Similar for time.

The number of cases you need to consider will render your regex unmaintainably complex.

So please just use a few separate replacements :-)

Comment: How would i find date n time to replace?

Comment: You can find plenty of answers about that, just search around.